# Css Vertical Menu Fly Out

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

The submenu of the vertical dropdown portion of my .css-driven menu has an issue. In the jsfiddle example, high lighting 'Bedroom Furniture' under 'Products' displays 'Bunk Beds'. While Bunk Beds' is being displayed, the menu option below (Home Office) isn't selectable (actually, it CAN be selected if the mouse is moved to the far right of Home Office). I've exhausted all of my ideas and any help would be appreciated.

I think the issue is in the 'second level vertical drop down' section of the CSS (CSS snippet...please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mf3y6Lj6/) example)

```
    .rmenu li ul li:hover ul li a {
    /*padding: 0px 0px 0px 33px;*/
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    background: #e8dec7;
    /*background color for submenu            hovered text*/
    color: #51db29;
    /* this is the color of the sub-sub   menu text. I made the color (#51db29) 'unusual' as an example. Should be changed to something less jarring (of course) */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-width:100px;
    position: relative;
    left: 175px;
    top: -35px;
    /* display 3rd level to the right*/
}
/* -- Appearance of second vertical dropdown menu hovered (submenu of first level vertical menu) -- */
 .rmenu li ul li:hover ul li:hover a {
    color: #000000;
    /*hovered text color*/
    min-width:100px;
}
/* ----
```

Comment: The jsFiddle is not working for me (Chrome 40.0.2214.94)

Comment: For whatever reason, you have to scroll the run box all the way to the left to see the menu in jfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mf3y6Lj6/1/

try this :

```
   <div id="header">
       <div id="nav">
           <ul>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu1</a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#"></a>submenu
                           <ul>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li>submenu</li>
                       <li>submenu</li>
                       <li>submenu</li>
                       <li>submenu</li>

                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu2</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                    <a href="#">Menu3</a>
                   <ul>

                       <li>submenu</li>

                       <li>submenu</li>
                       <li><a href="#"></a>submenu
                           <ul>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">sub sub menu</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>

                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu4</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                   <a href="#">Menu5</a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>

   </div>


    ul, li {
    margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; text-decoration:none; color:#fff}
    a { text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff}
    #nav ul {
    width:100%;}
    #nav ul li {
    float:left; padding:0 15px; line-height:40px;}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}


#header {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #808080;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 3px #000;
    float: left;
    height: 50px;
    width: 87%;
}
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 51px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}
    #nav ul > li:hover {
        background-color: #000;
    }

#nav ul li > ul {
    background-color: #000;
    display: none;

    position: absolute;
    top: 59px;
    width: 150px;
}

    #nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display:block} 
#nav ul li > ul > li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    width: 100%;
}

#nav ul li > ul > li > ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 pink;
    display: none;
    left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
    #nav ul li > ul > li:hover ul {
    display:block}

#nav ul li > ul > li > ul > li {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 pink;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. While your solution does provide for a completely new css driven menu system, if there's anyone who can look at the code I posted on jsfiddle and give a suggestion on how to modify it, it would be appreciated. There's a lot more css that would have to be modified if I started from scratch with the above solution. PLEASE NOTE: When viewing the jsfiddle, the vertical separator must be dragged to the left for my example to appear properly...not sure why. Many thanks!

Comment: Broke down the elements and figured out how to integrate your solution into my code. Many thanks!